# Can I change the default mail recipient on cron jobs?

Tags: linux, configuration, cron

I believe that if there is any output from a cronjob it is mailed to the user who the job belongs to. I think you can also add something like `MAILTO=vivek@nixcraft.in` at the top of the cron file to change where the output is sent to.

**Can I set an option so that cron jobs system-wide will be emailed to** `root` **instead of to the user who runs them?** (i.e. so that I don't have to set this in each user's cron file)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check `/etc/crontab` file and set `MAILTO=root` in there. Might also need in `/etc/rc` file

`crond` seems to accept MAILTO variable, I guess I am not sure completely but its worth a try changing the environment variable for crond before it is started. Like in `/etc/sysconfig/crond` or `/etc/rc.d/init.d/crond` script which sources the earlier file.

Example:

```
[centos@centos scripts]$ strings /usr/sbin/crond | grep -i mail
ValidateMailRcpts
MailCmd
cron_default_mail_charset
usage:  %s [-n] [-p] [-m <mail command>] [-x [
CRON_VALIDATE_MAILRCPTS
mailed %d byte%s of output but got status 0x%04x
[%ld] no more grandchildren--mail written?
MAILTO
/usr/sbin/sendmail
mailcmd too long
[%ld] closing pipe to mail
MAIL
```

Comment: Thanks very much! +1. Perhaps put the bottom part of your answer in a preformat / code format?

Answer (score 9):

Put `MAILTO=root` in `/etc/default/cron`. This file contains cron's default settings.

`man 5 crontab` says,

> If MAILTO is defined (and non-empty), mail is sent to the user so
>   named.

Refer: http://man.cx/cron(1)#heading4

Comment: where? for each user's crontab file?

Comment: @Nikhil check my updated answer.

Comment: it works for only the users' whose crontab has it. Will it work, if any of the users' do not have this variable set? I think @Cwd has asked specifically for a global setting that for all users.

Comment: @SachinDivekar -1 Nikhil is right. Also you edited my question and changed the meaning of it. The edited meaning does align with your answer, but this is not what i was asking.

Comment: @cwd sorry to edit your question. Is setting `MAILTO` in `/etc/default/cron` working for you?

Comment: @SachinDivekar - it's alright. Yes, that is working. Thank you for trying to help.

Comment: @cwd so I think my edits were reflecting the same meaning.

Comment: @SachinDivekar - ok i will edit your answer and then once the edits are accepted i will upvote.

Comment: This is not working for me. I have set the MAILTO in the default file and restarted cron service, but it's still sending to root (I'm trying to send to an external email address)

Comment: The `/etc/default/cron` has been deprecated, use `/etc/init/cron.conf` instead.